# Extract first two parts of each line using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a space-delimited file that looks like this:

```
0   22:16050847:T:C 0   16050847
0   rs62224609:16051249:T:C 0   16051249
0   22:16051250:G:A 0   16051250
0   GSA-rs138295790 0   16057310
```

How can I modify the second column so I extract only the first two parts? I would like my output to look like this:

```
0   22:16050847 0   16050847
0   rs62224609:16051249 0   16051249
0   22:16051250 0   16051250
0   GSA-rs138295790 0   16057310
```

Answer (score 2):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{split($2,a,":"); $2=(length(a)>1)? a[1]":"a[2] : $2}1' file
```

The output:

```
0 22:16050847 0 16050847
0 rs62224609:16051249 0 16051249
0 22:16051250 0 16051250
0 GSA-rs138295790 0 16057310
```

---

- `split($2,a,":")` - split the 2nd field into array `a` by separator `:`

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk:

```
gawk '{split($2,a,/[:-]/,c); $2 = sprintf("%s%c%s", a[1], c[1], a[2])} 1' file
0 22:16050847 0 16050847
0 rs62224609:16051249 0 16051249
0 22:16051250 0 16051250
0 GSA-rs138295790 0 16057310
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, assuming your file is called `my_file` and you're using the bash shell. It should be easier to understand and apply to similar problems:

```
paste -d ' ' <(awk '{print $1}' my_file) \
  <(awk '{print $2}' my_file | sed 's/:.:.//' ) \
  <(awk '{print $3" "$4}' my_file)
```

So for each line of the inputs, `paste` merges the subsequent sections with a space delimiter, given by `<()`.

- The first awk section pulls out the first column entry
- The second awk section takes the middle column and removes the second column, removing any :T:C like part
- The third pulls out the remaining columns.

The result is:

```
0 22:16050847  0 16050847
0 rs62224609:16051249  0 16051249
0 22:16051250 0 16051250
0 GSA-rs138295790 0 16057310
```

Comment: Assuming you have a shell with process substitution like e.g. `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -lpe 's/^\S+\s+[^:]+:[^:]+\K\S+//' file
```

With GNU `sed`:

```bash
sed -E ':t s/:\w+//2; tt' file
```

Output:

```
0   22:16050847 0   16050847
0   rs62224609:16051249 0   16051249
0   22:16051250 0   16051250
0   GSA-rs138295790 0   16057310
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash:

```
while read -r f1 f2 rest; do
   printf '%s' "$f1" "$(expr " $f2" : '\([^:]*:[^:]*\).*' \| " $f2")" "$rest"; echo
   # the lone echo provides for the newline
done < yourfile
```

`read` will split the fields into `$f1`, `$2`, and all the remaining shall be clumped into the `$rest`. Then on the 2nd field, `$f2`, we run `expr` to extract the first and second colon-delimited fields. If this is not possible, then we end up using the `$f2` variable itself.

Sed:

```
sed -e '
   s/[^[:space:]]\{1,\}/\
&\
/2
   :loop
      s/\n\(.*:.*\):.*\n/\n\1\n/
   tloop
   s/\n//g
' yourfile
```

We first envelop the 2nd field with `\n` and then run a loop around this region till there is just two fields (or, one field delimiter) left.

Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\G[^:\h]+:[^:\h]+\K\S+//,next while /\S\h+\S/g' yourfile

perl -pe 's/^\h*\S+\h+(?:(?!:)\S)+:(?:(?!:)\S)+\K\S+//' yourfile

perl -F'(\h+)' -lane '
   /:/ and $_ = join ":", (/[^:]+/g)[0,1] for $F[/^\h/?4:2];
   print @F;
' yourfile
```

---

### Result

```
0   22:16050847 0   16050847
0   rs62224609:16051249 0   16051249
0   22:16051250 0   16051250
0   GSA-rs138295790 0   16057310
```